# Dados sendo inseridos corretamente apenas no modo debug

Tags: php, mysqli, debug, importação

Estou trabalhando numa importação de arquivo `.txt` em que os elementos são separados por `|`. Até aí tudo certo, o arquivo é interpretado, os valores são armazenados num array e, após, eu preciso inserir os valores no banco de dados. Para isso, criei pequenas funções com o objetivo de separar as responsabilidades.

É nessa parte que entra o problema, vamos dizer assim.

```
function inserir_notas_entrada($fornecedores, $notas, $arquivo) {
require("utils/conexao.php");
require_once("utils/util.php");

$query = "";
foreach ($notas as $nota => $a) {

    $part = function () use ($a, $conn, $fornecedores) {
        foreach ($fornecedores as $fornecedor => $f) {
            if ($f[1] == $a[3]) {
                $cnpj = ($f[4] != "") ? formatar_cnpf_cnpj($f[4]) : formatar_cnpf_cnpj($f[5]);
                $busca_fornecedor = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT CODIGO_FORNECEDOR FROM fornecedores WHERE CNPJ_CPF = '$cnpj'");
                $dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($busca_fornecedor);
            }
        }
        return $dados['CODIGO_FORNECEDOR'];
    };

    $serie = $a[6];
    $num_doc = $a[7];
    $chave = $a[8];
    $dt_doc = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(formatar_data_sped($a[9])));
    $dt_e = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(formatar_data_sped($a[10])));
    $val_doc = floatval(str_replace(",", ".", $a[11]));
    $val_desc = floatval(str_replace(",", ".", $a[13]));
    $val_itens = floatval(str_replace(",", ".", $a[15]));
    $val_outras = floatval(str_replace(",", ".", $a[21]));

    $verifica_chave_nota = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT CHAVE_NFE FROM entradas WHERE CHAVE_NFE = '$chave'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($verifica_chave_nota) <= 0) {

        $cod_f = $part();
        echo $cod_f."</br>";

        $query .= "INSERT INTO entradas (DATA_ENTRADA, DATA_NOTA, CHAVE_NFE, NRO_NOTA, SERIE_NOTA, COD_FORNECEDOR, TOTAL_PRODUTOS, TOTAL_OUTRAS, TOTAL_DESCONTO, TOTAL_NOTA, ARQUIVO)
            VALUES ('$dt_e', '$dt_doc', '$chave', '$num_doc', '$serie', '$cod_f', '$val_itens', '$val_outras', '$val_desc', '$val_doc', '$arquivo');\n";
    }
}
```

}

Quando eu executo a função acima, o retorno dela é esse: 
[image: Impressão do código do fornecedor, resultado de um selec no banco de dados]

Porém, quando executo o código através do debug, o resultado é diferente (e também correto): 
[image: Resultado esperado]

Eu encontrei duas maneiras de resolver isso, mas não acredito que sejam as ideais. A primeira seria executar a query diretamente no laço foreach. A segunda opção é incluir um pequeno `usleep()`, mas comprometeria a velocidade dependendo da quantidade informacional.

Teria alguma forma de resolver isso?

OBS: Os testes estão sendo realizados localmente.

Comment: Já verificou  o  timeout do  servidor de produção  ?

Comment: Seria a diretiva `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` encontrado mo my.ini? Se for está setada em 50...